# $('document').value="" in IE 8.0

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, prototypejs

We are having tough time to solve this .

```
$('document').value=""
```

in IE is not assigning the value to empty string. But this works well in FF.

Comment: I don't know Protoype.js, but if `$('document')` selects the `document` object, then the question is why you want to set `value` on it? It does not have such a property.

Comment: @Felix: no, `$('document')` is like `document.getElementById('document')`

Comment: @user: Can you show us your markup (especially the parts containing the form)?

Comment: @MarcelKorpel: Thanks, NVM then... next time I keep my mouth shut :D

Comment: 'code' else if(id=='addpdfdetail') 
  {
   if($('document'))
    $('document').value="";   
   if($('DocumentTitle'))
    $('DocumentTitle').value="";
   if($('doctxt'))
    $('doctxt').value="";
   if($('documentKey'))
    $('documentKey').value="";
   if($('documentPath'))
    $('documentPath').value="";
   if( $('showdocdiv')){
    $('showdocdiv').hide();
    $('browsedocfileid').show();
   }
   if($('docpreviewkey'))
    $('docpreviewkey').value="";
   if($('docpreviewpath'))
    $('docpreviewpath').value="";
   if($('docpreviewfilename'))
    $('docpreviewfilename').value="";
  }

Comment: @user430333 — edit your question please, don't dump code into comments, and that is just more JS, I don't see any markup there.

Answer (score -1):

It should be $(document).attr('value', '') probably, though i don't understand why are you trying to assign a value attribute to the document object.

Comment: `$('document')` selects an element with ID `document`.

Comment: And there isn't an `attr` method

Comment: hmm didn't notice its prototype

Comment: thank you all.Here is a post of a similar issue we were facing and the  fix is suggested in this..http://gusiev.com/2009/04/clear-upload-file-input-field/